# XAP failed to initialize device and virtualbox manager does not open

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, virtualbox, xamarin-android-player

I updated windows recently.I also updated xamarin studio 6.1.1 and now not able to initialize the device. Everything was working perfectly before updates. I keep getting error:
failed to initialize device. VBoxManage command failed.See log for further details.
As I read on other threads, I was trying to open virtual boxmanager window and delete device.
I was not able to open virtual boxmanager window. so uninstalled virtual box, installed new version. then uninstalled xap and reinstalled. still getting error.
Which log should I check for details.? 
checked VT-x in the BIOS. it is enabed. Not able to open virtual boxmanager.
Also tried diabling and enabling virtualbox NDIS6 bridged networking driver.

Comment: XAP is no longer supported.  It's recommended to either use the VS.NET Emulator or the Android x86 one

Comment: since when is it not supported? I remember I used it a week ago. Does VS.NET Emulator or the Android x86 will work well and fast with xamarin studio?

Comment: for whatever reason they didn't make a big announcement, but it hasn't been updated in almost a year.  The new x86 emulator from Google is actually pretty good.

Comment: oh. Thank you very much Jason for the updates. I'll try google emultor.

Comment: I tried using google emulator. but it takes so much time to launch. Anything to do with configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin Android Player has been deprecated since June 8, 2016.

Ref: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/

> Note that the Xamarin Android Player has been deprecated. For more information, see the announcement in this blog post.

Ref: https://blog.xamarin.com/live-from-dotnetconf-cycle-7-xamarin-studio-6-and-more/