# Xamarin Android Player stuck on acquiring IP

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

trying to launch XAP and it's just stuck loading, I checked the settings and it's stuck on 'Acquiring IP'. I've tried to repair it in Control panel& programs, same thing. It worked fine yesterday, I didn't change anything.

Using API 19, and Windows 7.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922719/xap-failed-to-initialize-device-and-virtualbox-manager-does-not-open/39924764#39924764

Answer (score 2):

Xamarin Android Player is discontinued, it is recommended to use Android simulators for Visual Studio or Google x86 emulators