# Xamarin Android Player do not run

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I am working on Windows 8.i 32 bits, Visual Studio 2013, Xamarin, etc..

I have also installed Oracle VM Installed.

I was working Nexus4 (kitKat) and Jelly Bean Emulator from Visual Studio and Xamarin Studio.

But suddenly Nexus emulator did not appear any more. When i try to open Xamarin Android Player it did not open... It just appear ServiceManager.exe in Task Manager for a few seconds and disappear.

I deleted all Xamarin package and installed the last versión is the following order

> XamarinInstaller.exe
>
> XamarinStudio-6.1.2.44.msi
>
> gtk-sharp-2.12.38.msi
>
> jdk-8u112-windows-i586.exe
>
> XAP-Beta-15.43-v0.6.5-amd64.exe

But the problem remains.
Anyone had the same problem I have?

What i am missing?

Thanks

Comment: XAP is deprecated : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922719/xap-failed-to-initialize-device-and-virtualbox-manager-does-not-open/39924764#39924764 Try using a Android Virtual Device w/ Intel Haxm or Genymotion...

Comment: Thanks... it Works for me till 11/30/16... I will try to visual studio emulator for Android...