# Application Icon not showing in the Android Emulator

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I followed the Phoneword example from the Xamarin.Android tutorial and I was able to deploy the application to an Android emulator. However the application opens and runs at startup without any problem.

If I close the app, I don't see any Icon on the desktop of the emulator for the app[image].
I have already defined the path as @drawable/icon.

How can I show this Icon please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Xamarin Android Player is deprecated, you should convert to using AVD w/ Intel's Haxm  (or Genymotion is another choice)

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39924764/4984832

- Open "All Apps", search or pan the screen and your will find your app in the list of all installed applications, you can then long-press your app's icon and add it to your home screen

Ref: http://www.androidcentral.com/how-add-and-arrange-home-screens-android-44-kitkat

Comment: Thanks. However this is not very clear. I am completely new to Xamarin development. What do I use to replace this? Where do I download a current one and will that solve my problem of having the icon displayed?

Comment: @user2320476 Two totally separate issues, the icon issue has nothing to due with Xamarin, that is an Android feature/function. For the emulator, review : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/android-sdk-emulator/