# Xamarin Android Player for Mac does not work

Tags: macos, xamarin

I installed Xamarin Android Player 0.6.5 on Mac OS 10.13.4. When I try to start the program, I get the following notification:

*Kernel Drivers are not loaded.
XAP will now ask for elevated permissions so that it can reload the required kernel drivers*

What to do?

Comment: "will now ask for elevated permissions" Well? Does it? Do you disagree that the drivers are not loaded?

Comment: I click OK, then it requires a password from the computer. So I entered the password three times and after that I received an error message: An unhandled exception has occurred. No suitable adapter.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922719/xap-failed-to-initialize-device-and-virtualbox-manager-does-not-open/39924764#39924764